# Why is the button not working on my tkinter temp converter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I need to make a temperature converter for a class through tkinter. All the labels and buttons come up, but my button does not do anything when clicked. I have tried multiple different definitions of the command with no luck.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
label=Label(root,text="TEMPERATURE CONVERTER")
label.pack(side=TOP)
entry1=Entry(root)
entry1.place(x=300,y=50)
button1=Button(root,text="Convert")
button1.place(x=300,y=100)
label1=Label(root,text="Temperature in Celsius: ")
label1.place(x=100,y=50)
label2=Label(root,text="Temperature in Fahrenheit: ")
label2.place(x=100,y=150)
label3=Label(root)
label3.place(x=300,y=150)
var1=DoubleVar()
entry1=Entry(root,textvariable=var1)
def click1():
    label3.config(str(var1.get)+ 32 * 1.8)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", click1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems with your function.  Are you even looking for the error messages?  Because I got several when I ran your code.

1. Button callbacks are passed a parameter. You weren't looking for one, so you get a `TypeError`.
2. "`var1.get`" is a function.  To fetch the value, you have to *call* the it.
3. You were multiplying the result of `str`, instead of multiplying the numbers and converting that.
4. You have to tell `config` what thing to change.  In your case, that's `text`.
5. Your formula for converting C to F is wrong.

This works, assuming you add `root.mainloop()` at the end.

```
def click1(e):
    label3.config(text=str(var1.get() * 1.8 + 32))
```